# Is it legal to perform communication with authorities for money in Germany?

Tags: germany, commerce, online, administrative-law, municipal-bylaws

I've gone through some processes of communcation with the register of associations and noted that there's no clarity of the process except for law texts and obscure forum posts.

I thought, I'd would be nice to have a simple online plattform that offers standardized processes (founding/terminating an association, starting a small business) and takes you through the process by explaining what document and payments are required, what's already done, etc.

The customers pay an amount X for standardized texts and the intuitive explanation and overview provided by the platform. The platfrom makes no guarantee about the success of the actions, maybe refunds the fee if the process isn't successful. The platform also doesn't give any specific legal advice; it merely translates the law texts into concrete instructions for handing in documents. If there's need for notarial acts, it provides a connection to one like yellow/white pages, but doesn't interact with anyone on behalf of the customer.

Is it legal to run such a platform in Germany? For all cities in general?  If not, for a selection of cities if there's restrictions by state or municipal law?

Comment: What qualifications do you have? I mean if you want to wallpaper my home for money, you need a qualification as a professional wallpaperer.

Comment: Software developer. None in law-related professions. The platform would be run by a company, so I could hire employees with required professions if that's a requirement for making the platform legal.

Comment: I am pretty sure the company will need to have employees with legal qualifications.  As such, you should consult your own (paid for) lawyer who can explain what the exact requirements are.

Comment: Such cases are really disputed currently with the buzzword *legal tech*. It may be illegal now, but there are discussions if the law should be amended.

Comment: Look especially at the Rechtsdienstleistungsgesetz and relevant court decisions, e.g. the wenigermiete judgment. Also news: https://www.lto.de/recht/zukunft-digitales/

Answer (score 2):

### Systems like this risk crossing over into legal advice

In almost all jurisdictions only lawyers can do this.

If you keep your system as a simple automation of a paper process you should be fine but the minute it “translates the law texts into concrete instructions” you are giving legal advice. You can reproduce the law but only a lawyer can explain what it means.